# PHP - Questão sobre Seleção mais recente

Tags: php, mysql

Boas,

Criei ums cript que mostra todas as mensagens do utilizador limitada a 3.
O meu objeitvo é que as mensagens mostrem assim cada vez que sao recentes.

```
     MSG hora: 12:30 - OLA
     MSG hora: 12:31 - OLA
     MSG hora: 12:32 - OLA
```

O problema é que quando existe uma nova mensagem e já existem 3, ele apenas nao atualiza, mostra as 3 antigas, apenas passado +2 mensagens é que ele mostra mas de forma ASC (de cima para baixo) exemplo:

```
     MSG hora: 12:32 - OLA
     MSG hora: 12:31 - OLA
     MSG hora: 12:30 - OLA
```

E devia mostrar sempre a mais recente na 3º aqui:

```
     MSG hora: 12:30 - OLA
     MSG hora: 12:31 - OLA
     Mais recente ->>> MSG hora: 12:32 - OLA






     $message_from = "SELECT msg_content, msg_from, msg_date FROM public_messeger_reply WHERE msg_to = '". $_SESSION['u_id'] ."' AND msg_reply_id = '". $order_detail['ads_id'] ."' ORDER BY msg_date DESC LIMIT 3";
     $to_query = $con->query($message_from);


     if($to_query->num_rows > 0) {
       echo "<blockquote>";
        while($fetch_to = $to_query->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo "<p><b>Negociante:</b> ". $fetch_to['msg_content'] ." <small>". dateName($fetch_to['msg_date']) ."</small></p>";
              } 
      echo "</blockquote>";
     }
```

Comment: Ora, mas o DESC que vc está usando irá mostrar em ordem decrescente. Não deveria mudar para ASC?

Comment: Mas ASC mostra apartir dos mais antigos, eu quero os registos mais recentes...

Comment: Quando tem apenas 3 funciona com ASC, mas a partir de 4 já não funciona.

Comment: Exato...dvd.....

Comment: Como faço para ele funcionar...?

Comment: e como é o tipo de coluna da data?

Comment: a coluna eDATETIME

Comment: Extranho, `ORDER BY msg_date DESC LIMIT 3` aqui funcionou bem, sendo que `msg_date` é uma coluna tipo `DATETIME`

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo exato!

Comment: a ultima retornada aqui na minha tabela de visitas do meu site foi 2018-05-27 22:03:09

Comment: agora 2018-05-27 22:14:49

Comment: Tem certeza que `msg_date` é a coluna cujo tipo é DATETIME?

Comment: Sim tenho. em DESC ele mostra direito... Soque de CIMA para baixo, que queria DEBAIXO para cima que é ASC, mas nao mostra os recentes... :(

Comment: entendi, vc quer inverter a ordem na apresentação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use uma subquery para pegar apenas os últimos 3 registros, e em seguida ordenando-os de forma crescente (`ASC`):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT msg_content, msg_from, msg_date FROM public_messeger_reply
     WHERE msg_to = '". $_SESSION['u_id'] ."'
     AND msg_reply_id = '". $order_detail['ads_id'] ."'
     ORDER BY msg_date DESC 
     LIMIT 3) t
ORDER BY msg_date ASC;
```

Comment: Simplesmente nao mostra nada....

Comment: ... uai, perai

Comment: JA DEUU, apenas corrigi a variavel :D

Comment: Pois é, já tava ficando preocupado porque o código está correto rss

Comment: pra vc matutar, salva em um array e inverte os elementos dele

Comment: Obrigadao mano :D

Answer (score 0):

**Outra opção:** - para quem tem dificuldades de montar query mas conhece bem php!

```
if($to_query->num_rows > 0) {
   echo "<blockquote>";
    while($fetch_to = $to_query->fetch_assoc()) {
      //concatena acrescentando uma virgula ao final de cada loop  
      $result .= "<p><b>Negociante:</b> ". $fetch_to['msg_content'] ." <small>". dateName($fetch_to['msg_date']) ."</small></p>,";
    } 

    //retira a ultima virgula       
    $result=substr_replace($result, ',', -1);

    // Quebra o texto nas "," e transforma cada pedaço numa matriz
    $divisor = explode(",", $result);

    // Inverte os pedaços
    $reverso = array_reverse($divisor);

    // Junta novamente a matriz em texto
    $final = implode(" ", $reverso); // Junta com espaço

    echo $final;      

  echo "</blockquote>";
}
```